# Backbonejs model doesn't hit the correct url on fetch(), thus doesn't send any params

Tags: node.js, rest, backbone.js, model

I have this on the client:

```
var Article = Backbone.Model.extend({
    urlRoot: '/wiki'
});
var ArticleView = Backbone.View.extend({
   render: function(){
     var article = new Article({term:'test'});
     article.fetch(); //sends a request to wiki, not to wiki/:term as i want to
   }
});
```

and this on the server (node):

```
//Never gets hit
app.get('/wiki/:term', function(req, res){
    console.log('/wiki/term');
});

app.get('/wiki', function(req, res){
    console.log('/wiki');
    console.log(req.params.term); //produces 'undefined'
});
```

What do i need to do to make backbone fetch from the correct route (i.e wiki/:term) and actually send the term parameter to the server?

EDIT:
i was able to retrieve the request parameter on the server side using `req.query.term`, not `req.params.term`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var Article = Backbone.Model.extend({
    urlRoot: '/wiki',
    url: function () {
      return this.urlRoot + "/" + encodeURIComponent(this.get("term"));
    }
});
```